# How to remove lint from a shirt without a lint brush?

Tags: cleaning, substitute-tool, clothing

I am at the office right now and thanks to a new cotton jacket I wore on the way here, my shirt is covered in lint/fluffs.

Obviously this looks terrible and I would like to avoid making a bad/unclean impression to our customers.

Is there any way to get the shirt clean without a special lint brush? (which I don't have here)
Are there any tricks that can only be performed with household items available to me here at the office (or from a nearby supermarket)?

Comment: Regular clear tape or masking tape?

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of ways to remove lint from clothes without using a lint brush or a lint roller.

### Tape Method  <sup>[detailed instructions with videos](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Lint-from-Clothes#Tape_Method_sub)</sup>

#### What you'll need

- wide sticky paper (e.g. packing tape or duct tape)
- your hands

#### Steps

1. Lay your clothing on a clean, flat surface
2. Wrap some tape around your fingers with the sticky side pointing out
3. Dab the clothing with your *sticky hand* where needed
4. Replace the tape once it's full of lint
5. Repeat until lint-free

---

### Prevention

Add about a 1/4 cup (60 mL) of vinegar to the wash when laundering lint-ridden clothes.

*Source: [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Lint-from-Clothes)*

Comment: The clothes will not smell of vinegar will they?

Comment: I have not done this myself. But concerning the small amount of vinegar in relation to all the water you won't. The detergent will very likely neutralize the vinegar odor.

Answer (score 3):

Using rubber gloves might do the trick, just caress the shirt with the gloves and the static electricity should remove lint and pet hair.
Just make sure the gloves are new and dry.

Answer (score 3):

This happens to me sometimes too, I also have dogs at home so have to deal with the hair as well. I have found that in a jam with no lint brush a slightly damp washcloth will do the trick.

You must make sure that you ring it out the washcloth completely!
Lightly brush the washcloth over your jacket removing the lint.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to remove lint from clothes without using a lint brush or a lint roller. Use caution when trying the below methods, since they all can damage your clothing.

### DIY Lint Roller <sup>[detailed instructions with videos](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Lint-from-Clothes#DIY_Lint_Roller_sub)</sup>

#### What you'll need <sup>use one of the below</sup>

- Velcro tabs and a brush <sup>(see [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Clean-Velcro) for instructions on how to clean Velcro)</sup>
- a single-blade razor
- a pumice stone or a Sweater Stone
- a scouring pad  and some water

#### Steps

**Velcro**

1. Stick some Velcro tabs to the back of your brush
2. Use the hooked side to brush off lint

**Razor**

1. Hold the razor at a certain angle so you not cut into the cloth
2. Skim the fabric surface and get rid of the lint

**Stone**

1. Rub gently against surface of the clothing
2. Do not rub too hard and do not use on delicate fabric such as silk

**Scouring pad**

1. Slightly wet your scouring pad with water
2. Scrub your clothing gently with the damp scouring pad

---

### Prevention

Add about a cup of vinegar to the wash when laundering lint-ridden clothes.

*Source: [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Lint-from-Clothes)*