# How to get rid of this from wool coat

Tags: cleaning, clothing

I have a wool coat. I love it but it attract a lot fluff and this thing (as shown in picture). How can I make so the coat doesn’t attract it and how can I clean the coat as well? As it make me look ugly and not clean
[image: fluff and the thing]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove lint from a shirt without a lint brush?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6530/how-to-remove-lint-from-a-shirt-without-a-lint-brush)

Comment: Not a duplicate because the other one asks how to do it without the brush, but this one would accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar problem with my dog shedding.  Lint rollers don't really work.  Actually, I tried duct tape when my lint roller didn't work and that didn't even work.  So I got it dry cleaned to get the lint and hair off, and then followed this simple process.

What I do is I take the wool coat off and put it in the closet when I get home.  Then I do not take it out again until I put it on to leave the house.  The lint and dog hair getting on the coat came from the house, so since the coat never really goes in the house anymore, this solved the problem.  Just get the coat cleaned and keep it in the closet.  As long as you aren't going any linty places, this solves the lint attraction problem.  You can also take the coat off and store it or hang it up away from things if you go to other linty homes, etc.  Stay vigilant!

Comment: Vigi-lint, one might say

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried a lint roller? If it’s “pilling” with little balls of fiber still attached gently running a razor over it will remove them.

Answer (score 2):

I have also found that sticky tape works well. Wouldnt use gaff tape or anything too strong but just simple sticky tape is what I always use and havent had any issues with it. Not too expensive either!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue with one of my coats. My brother told me to put it on a hanger and hang it from somewhere and then wet your hands under running water and then wipe your coat down once and it picks all the fluff off, wash hands and repeat till like new again.

Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Lint roller followed by a pill remover or wool comb. Many different styles available. Can be used on many different clothing items to keep them smooth and smart looking.

[image: wool comb]

Answer (score 0):

I use my handy little fabric shaver. My white dog's fur on my black wool peacoat doesn't stand a chance.